# C# webbrowser control scrollbar not visible when resizing control

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

When I set webbrowser controls Width and Height at form_load and navigate then it doesn't show scrollbars.

If I leave width and height to default then the control shows scrollbars.

How can I show scrollbar after setting width and height of webbrowser control at runtime? Setting ScrollBarsEnabled property doesn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use
        **WebBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;**
at your form_load event or you can set 'Dock' property manually at designer.

DockStyle.Fill means the control fill in space of its parent. The parent can be form, panel, tab control, etc. So WebBrowser will follow to whatever size of its parent.

Hope this help